# Presenting modally not proper in iPad

Tags: ios, swift

On the click of a next button(which is in the cart view which in the image is hidden due to the view presented), I'm presenting a view modally. In iPhone, it looks like so....

[image]

On the click of that next button to present the view modally this is the code written...

```
let vc = PresentedUserDetailsViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And in the `PresentedUserDetailsViewController` which is the presented view, I have initialized the following...

```
let menuHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2
init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    transitioningDelegate = self
}
```

But when I run in an iPad Air 2 simulator the view is presented like so...

[image]

What should be done to make the presented view appear as in an iPhone..?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like auto-layout issue. Maybe you could start by setting the Devices to universal in the general settings, so it will be fullscreen like so:

[image] 
I can see that the button "From contacts" is not fully centered on the iPad screen. Maybe you have used fixed values for the layout? In that case you should use the "Center horizontally in container" constraint instead and generally set the width and height constraints relative to the safe area. Have you tried on a different screen like the iPhone 5? You might also see some issues there.

Comment: this is an iPhone only app. So I can't set the Devices in deployment info to universal..I'm trying in iPad since apple wants even iPhone only devices to appear on iPad..